# Simultaneously compiling two or more projects with Compilation Mode

Tags: compilation-mode

I haven't found a way to use Compilation Mode in two projects simultaneously.  Starting compilation in a second project kills the compilation of the first.

Is it possible to run two compilations simultaneously, perhaps with separate buffers `*compilation*` and `*compilation<2>`?

I'm compiling with command `helm-make-projectile`: https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make
What I'm describing may not be a limitation of Compilation Mode but rather `helm-make-projectile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of the `compile` function:

> To run more than one compilation at once, start one then rename
>   the ‘*compilation*’ buffer to some other name with
>   M-x rename-buffer.  Then *switch buffers* and start the new compilation.
>   It will create a new ‘*compilation*’ buffer.